# Loading time Power Query

Tags: powerquery

I'm having big troubles with an Excel file where I'm using Power Query to merge multiples Excel files on a single Excel table. The problem started because the Power Query editor gets too slow when I try to modify something in the DB query (see snip below). The "DB" query is where I merge the content of all the other queries. In the picture below, you can find the 8 different queries that I have in my Power Query editor.

The thing is that it can take even 3 - 4 minutes to load the preview of the "DB" query, and I think the root cause is related with one file called "Control plan". Like you can see in the snip, at the bottom right corner,  the loading can go until 25,8 MB (and much more), even if the "Control Plan" file is a very simple table of 25 KB. It is true that 4 queries out of the 8, (CONTROL, TARGET, STERRING - and STEERING +) are linked to this "Control Plan" file, so I'm wondering if it has something to do with this.

I thank you very much if someone could help me with this, I'm colpletely stuck with this.

Thank you -/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the reasons your query:s preview is slow id, when doing the preview, it creates a preview of each step, and this query has a lot of steps!

Break it up into separate queries so that each source table is filtered and removes unnecessary columns as much as possible before merging, plus a last query that only merges them all together and any steps that can't be done before merging.

The query editor UI will feel much faster, debugging will be easier, and you'll find ways to improve what you're doing when each part is its own separated piece of code.

(Also, if you use a buffer function, try removing it. I've found it's often faster to *not* buffer.)